# Mark File For Removal from Python?

Tags: python, file

In one of my scripts, I need to delete a file that could be in use at the time. I know that I can't remove the file that is in use until it isn't anymore, but I also know that I can mark the file for removal by the Operating System (Windows XP). How would I do this in Python?

Comment: Same way you would in any other programming language.

Comment: Ok, what would that be? I don't program in many other languages, and don't know how to do this in the ones I do use. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: On linux, you can remove the file even if it's in use. The processes using it will still have the file handle open until they exit, so it's recoverable in that sense. Windows does things differently

Comment: Which OS?  Since Windows and Linux are different, which matters for answering this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import win32file
import win32api
win32file.MoveFileEx("/path/to/lockedfile.ext", None ,
                 win32file.MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)
```

Comment: Thanks! Who knew that this would be so easy! You saved my entire application, @Paulo Scardine!

Answer (score 7):

...and another version which doesn't depend on pywin32 binaries.

```
import ctypes
MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT = 4

ctypes.windll.kernel32.MoveFileExA("/path/to/lockedfile.ext", None,
                                       MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`MoveFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240%28VS.85%29.aspx) function:

> If dwFlags specifies MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT and *lpNewFileName* is NULL, MoveFileEx registers the *lpExistingFileName* file to be deleted when the system restarts. If *lpExistingFileName* refers to a directory, the system removes the directory at restart only if the directory is empty.